# Record to be added after approval in Apex 5.1.3

Tags: oracle-apex

I am creating an application in apex 5.1.3 that will allow a general user to add a record to a table by filling a form, but it should first be approved by the admin user.  Is there a possible way to do so without the use of processes?

Comment: No.  You will either need to store in a staging table or use status' to approve the records.

Comment: I am new to apex, what does staging table mean?

Comment: I mean an intermediary table where you store the data before it is processed according to your needs (e.g. in your case approving or rejecting the data).